# Split array based on element contents?

Tags: javascript, arrays, grouping

Let's say my elements look like this:

```js
const words = [
 'duck foo bar',
 'duck',
 'duck bing ',
 'bing',
 'Bloop#12 goose',
 'duck 12',
 'duck goose',
  ...
]
```

What I'd like is to split this into chunks where 'goose' is the final element in a chunk:

```js
const words = [
 [
   'duck foo bar',
   'duck',
   'duck bing',
   'bing',
   'Bloop#12 goose',
 ], 
 [
   'duck 12',
   'duck goose',
 ], 
 [
  ...
 ],
];
```

There's no regularity to how many elements precede a 'goose', nor what is in each element except that 1) goose is always the last part of an element, and 2) goose never appears in any other element besides the one I want a chunk to end on (i.e. I never get 'goose foo', but I might get 'duck goose')

Comment: what is the problem (with your code)?

Comment: @NinaScholz if I'm honest, I got mixed up and tried to use `array.split('goose')` which is so nonsensical it wasn't worth posting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could reduce the array and have a look to the previous string and add an array to the result set for a new group.

```js
const
    words = ['duck foo bar', 'duck', 'duck bing ', 'bing', 'Bloop#12 goose', 'duck 12', 'duck goose'],
    separator = 'goose',
    groups = words.reduce((r, s, i, a) => {
        if (!i || a[i - 1].includes(separator)) r.push([]);
        r[r.length - 1].push(s);
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(groups);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. This should do what you're looking for.

```js
const words = [
 'duck foo bar',
 'duck',
 'duck bing ',
 'bing',
 'Bloop#12 goose',
 'duck 12',
 'duck goose'
]

const answer = []
let temp = []
for(let i = 0; i < words.length; i++){
  if(words[i].includes('goose')){
    temp.push(words[i])
    answer.push(temp)
    temp = []
  } else{
    temp.push(words[i])
  }
}

console.log(answer)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with a simple `forEach` loop. In my example below I store the values first temporally.

Then I push the chunk into the new array if the word contains `goose`.

```js
const words = [
 'duck foo bar',
 'duck',
 'duck bing ',
 'bing',
 'Bloop#12 goose',
 'duck 12',
 'duck goose',
 'abc'
]

const n = []
let tmp = [];
words.forEach((w) => {
  if (! w.includes('goose')) {
    tmp.push(w);
  } else {
    tmp.push(w);
    n.push(tmp);
    tmp = [];
  } 
  
});

console.log(n)
```

Comment: @AncientSwordRage Thank you for editing. My english is horrible. Hope my code helps a little bit?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the first solution that came up in my mind.

We keep pushing elements to `temp` array until we get a string containing the word `goose`.

```js
const words = [
 'duck foo bar',
 'duck',
 'duck bing ',
 'bing',
 'Bloop#12 goose',
 'duck 12',
 'duck goose',
];

const splits = [];
let temp = [];

words.forEach(word => {
 if(word.includes('goose')) {
    temp.push(word);
  splits.push(temp);
  temp = [];
 } else {
    temp.push(word);
 }
})

console.log(splits)
```

Answer (score 0):

This would also work.

```js
const words = [
  "duck foo bar",
  "duck",
  "duck bing ",
  "bing",
  "Bloop#12 goose",
  "duck 12",
  "duck goose",
];

const output = [];

let chunk = [];
words.forEach((item) => {
  const splits = item.split(" ");
  const last =  splits[splits.length - 1];
  if(last === "goose") {
    chunk.push(item)
    output.push(chunk)
    chunk = [];
  } else {
    chunk.push(item)
  }
})

console.log(output);
```